# WPF Clicking on a dynamic menu item and returning the name?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a file menu, where on load, some `menuItems` are populated from filenames in a directory.

```
<MenuItem 
    x:Name="LayoutLoad" 
    Header="Load saved layout" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Width="200"
    />
```

//on load (code behind)

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles("Settings/layouts");
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Count(); i++)
{
    MenuItem item = new MenuItem {
        Header = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i]),
        Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePaths[i])
    };
    item.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Chooselayout);
    LayoutLoad.Items.Add(item);
}
```

My click event linked to the items is:

```
public void Chooselayout(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

     string fileName = ((MenuItem)sender).Name;
     var serializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(dockingManager);

     using (var stream = new StreamReader(fileName))
         serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

the line `string fileName = ((MenuItem)sender).Name;` fails. Can I return the name of the clicked item in this way? Am I simply casting wrongly? Or going about this in the incorrect way?

Thank you.

Comment: *"the line string fileName = ((MenuItem)sender).Name; fails"* -- can you describe exactly what fails about it? Why are you using `Name` instead of `Tag` or `DataContext`?

Comment: Ah, after fixing a typo, the error is actually: `Could not find file bin/release/ONE`, It should be looking for `bin/release/Settings/layouts/ONE`. Do I adjust the `Name=` to the full path? Thank you

Comment: The rules for element names in WPF are stricter than the rules for paths and file names.  For example, I don't believe element names can contain spaces.  Perhaps you should use `Tag` instead.  And yes, you need to be attaching the full path (or at least the relative path) and not just the file name.

Comment: @anti 1. Don't use `Name`. Use `Tag`. 2. Clearly, if you had to pass a relative path to `Directory.GetFiles()`, the files aren't in the current working directory. So yes, you need to pass a path to the actual file if you want to open it.

Comment: Thank you! using `string fileName = ((MenuItem)sender).Tag;` gives me `cannot convert type' object' to 'string'`

Comment: So cast it, just like you had to cast `sender` from `object` to `MenuItem`: `string fileName = (string)((MenuItem)sender).Tag;`

Comment: Ah sorry, obviously `string fileName = ((MenuItem)sender).Tag.ToString();`

Comment: .. or your way. :)

Comment: Success! Thank you both for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for element names in WPF are stricter than the rules for paths and file names.  For example, I don't believe `Name` can contain spaces or slashes. I suggest you use `Tag` instead (and cast back to `string` in your handler).

Also, look at how you are listing your files:

`Directory.GetFiles("Settings/layouts")`

You are looking for files that exist in `<working directory>/Settings/layouts/`.  Yet, when you create your `StreamReader`, you are only giving it the *name* of the file, so it's going to look for the file in `<working directory>/`.  You need to give it the absolute path or the full relative path.